# Cutting a substring from a radix tree of strings

Tags: c, string, radix

my problem is this: I want to search through a radix tree of strings, each having a unique number, until I find the one with the number given as function parameter. While I search the tree recursively I need to update the string (concatenate current string with the new one as I go down and cut off the suffix as I get back from recurrence). Each tree node has a pointer to its child and its brother. The function is as follows and it's not working for some reason.

```
void prev(struct tree *t, int w, int start, int end) {
  char *newWord = "";
  bool f = false;
  bool *found = &f;

  void prevRec(struct tNode *t, 
    int w, int start, int end, char *soFar) {
    if (t != NULL) {
      char *updatedWord = malloc(strlen(soFar) + strlen(t->word) + 1);
      strcpy(updatedWord,soFar);
      strcat(updatedWord,t->word);
      int length = strlen(t->word);
      if (t->count == w) {
        *found = true;
        if ((start > -1) && (start <= end)) {
          newWord = updatedWord;
        } else newWord = "";
      } else {
        if (!*found) {
          prevRec(t->child,w,start,end,updatedWord);
          char *sub = substring(updatedWord, 0, strlen(updatedWord) - length);
          free(updatedWord);
          updatedWord = sub;
          prevRec(t->brother,w,start,end,updatedWord);
          sub = substring(updatedWord, 0, strlen(updatedWord) - length);
          free(updatedWord);
          updatedWord = sub;
        }
      } 
    }
  } //prevRec

  prevRec(t->root->child,w,start,end,newWord);
  if (strlen(newWord) < 1 || end > strlen(newWord)) {
    printf("ignored\n");
    globalFound = 1;
  } else {
    char *tmp = substring(newWord,start,end - start + 1);
   insert(t,tmp); 
   free(tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: I should add that once I find the string I want to cut a substring from it starting from the position denoted as "start" and ending at "end"

Comment: "search through a radix tree of strings ... until I find the one ..." is the goal.    "it's not working" is the problem and not very descriptive.  Suggest detailing the problem, observe and expected results.